# My images are not displaying when I send a link

Tags: wordpress, image, facebook, jpeg, facebook-opengraph

I use wordpress.org and bluehost. My site url is http://www.midnightmassmusic.com , and everytime I share an article either through text message, or onto fb, it doesn't display an image. I used facebook debugger and it keeps say there's no og description, and it's an invalid content type. How do I fix this? I even added facebook and google to hotlink protection, wondering if that was causing it. It didn't help. I use Yoast, didn't help. Is it possibly my image optimizer (Ewww) plugin interfering? Or are my image files not formatted correctly? Bluehost won't help me because they claim it's Facebook's problem..but it's not. The same error is occuring when sharing through text.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no `og:decription` tag in your source, so Facebook is right about that. That being said, your `og:image` is not accessible in public. I get a 403 error when i try to load it in the browser: https://midnightmassmusic.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/20181230_1552042-1-e1547951786467.jpg

Btw, your image size would be 600x800, which is not an appropriate aspect ratio for og images. You should use 1200x630 according to the docs.

Comment: Hi. I am extremely new to wordpress. Why would my images be returning a 403 error? Could it be due t hotlink protection? When I visit my site on my phone or computer I see the images. How might I fix this problem>

Comment: i dunno, but you must make sure that og images are public. facebook needs to be able to read them. maybe there´s something wrong with your wp settings, or your htaccess file...

Comment: When I entered my url into an HTTP Header Check Tool to see if it's the Hotlink causing the 403, it keeps returning a 301 error. My htaccess file does have several Rewrites in it. I'm not sure how to correct that. I tried to add a snippet to it a while back to add expires headers, but perhaps I entered it in wrong and that's what's causing it to display the mod_rewrites? No clue. Anyways, how do I make the og:images public? Disable hotlink protection? Thank you so much for the help..I'm literally tearing my hair out.

Comment: well, that i would definitely disable, yeah

Comment: how did you resolve it? anything i can add to my answer, so other users get help immediately if they got the same problem?